# Adding A CRON function

Tags: yii

I basically have this very simple data manipulation function :

```
public function updateRecords(){
$now = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('c_date>"'.$now.'"');
Files::model()->updateAll(array('is_eop'=>1),$criteria);
}
```

I want this function to run automatically everytime the application is oppened, I was thinking of adding this to the SiteControlller but maybe there is a better way to implement a CRON function, note that the online server runs on XAMPP.
Thank You for your time!

Comment: If you want it to run every time a Controller/Action is called you can add an `init()` function to your base Controller class (_protected/components/Controller.php_). Depends on how often you want it to run I guess?

Comment: Well basically every time your run the application it should run once (I think thats enough),
I will try your method and let you know! Thanks

Comment: No problem :) This will run every time any controller/action is called. You could set a `SESSION` the first time it runs and then check for the `SESSION` in the `init()` and only run it if the `SESSION` doesn't exist

Comment: This would slow down the site, updating all records at the time the user logs on. This is precisely when you want the site to be as fast as possible. Wouldn't it be better to make a real CRON job, which would move the update workload away from the user-experience?

Comment: This is a great idea, how can I achieve that? The problem is, the online server is Windows OS/ XAMPP Based!